# Why I'm I getting NameError: name "type_check" is not defined when importing pandas, numpy and seaborn in jupyter notebook?

Tags: pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to do some data visualization with seaborne but as soon as I try to import numpy or pandas or seaborne I get a name error

I tried restarting the kennels but it won't work
It says name error : name 'type_check' is not defined

Comment: What is your version of `numpy`? Try `!pip show numpy` in your jupyter notebook. Do you use Anaconda or a standard python environment?